# Pandas: new column with largest value from existing columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am having a really hard time understanding how to do even basic data manipulation without iteration, so if I stop making sense, try to go easy on me. 
Let's suppose I have a dataframe `df` that looks like this:

```
        f1    f2    f3    f4
1       1     2     3     'Sari'
2       2     1     4     'Sally'
3       3     0     1     'Jose'
```

I want to know how to get the max integer in each row. I'm fine with storing it in a new column, f5. So, perhaps code that

```
df['f5'] = ??? #I'm stuck...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`df.max(axis=1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html):

```
In [2682]: df 
Out[2682]: 
   f1  f2  f3       f4
1   1   2   3   'Sari'
2   2   1   4  'Sally'
3   3   0   1   'Jose'

In [2684]: df['f5'] = df.select_dtypes('number').max(axis=1)
In [2685]: df                
Out[2685]: 
   f1  f2  f3       f4  f5
1   1   2   3   'Sari'   3
2   2   1   4  'Sally'   4
3   3   0   1   'Jose'   3
```

**`df.select_dtypes('number')`** selects only those columns which have `dtype` as `int` or `float`. This ensures that `max` calculation is done only on numerical columns not on string columns.

**`axis=1`** calculates the function on row-level.

**`axis=0`** calculates the function on column-level.

Comment: To be safe I would use: `df.select_dtypes('number').max(axis=1)`

Comment: @Erfan Agreed. Edited my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Holy crap I think I figured it out...

```
df['f5'] = df[['f1','f2','f3']].max(axis=1)
```

Let me know if there's a better way.

Comment: Thanks. Saw the comment about df.select_dtypes('number') which is obviously helpful if you have a lot more than 3 columns.

Comment: If the number of columns keep increasing, you will have to manually add it in the list `['f1','f2','f3']`.. So to avoid that, please check my answer.

Comment: Besides that, this won't work, did you try to run your code?

Comment: @philosofool I guess your code is missing `[]`. It should be `df['f5'] = df[['f1','f2','f3']].max(axis=1)`.

Comment: @Erfan It was hypothetical code, and so I didn't try to run it. The version I ran did work; in the version above, there are missing ```[ ]``` around the index to df, which I forgot. i.e ```df[['f1','f2','f3']].max(axis=1)```